# How to loop and plot correctly on 4D Nifti MRI image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have **4D NIFTI images** with **different dimensions [x,y,slices,frames]**, the first two are the spatial resolution, the third is slice number, while the last one is frame number, I tried to plot all the slices of a specific frame into one figure and update frame by frame using for loops instead of doing all the indexing manually as before, but I have a problem that my images are not updating the frame (except the last one down) as you can see in the attached photo, how can I solve this issue please ?? 
[image: NIFTI 4D Image]

```
#==================================
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#==================================
# load image (4D) [X,Y,Z_slice,time]
nii_img  = nib.load(path)
nii_data = nii_img.get_fdata()
#===================================================
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,3,constrained_layout=True)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('4D Nifti Image')
fig.suptitle('4D_Nifti 10 slices 30 time Frames', fontsize=16)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
slice_counter = 0
for i in range(30):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            if slice_counter<9:
                ax[j,k].cla()
                ax[j,k].imshow(nii_data[:,:,slice_counter,i],cmap='gray', interpolation=None)
                ax[j,k].set_title("frame {}".format(i))
                ax[j,k].axis('off')
                slice_counter+=1
            else:
                #---------------------------------
                ax[3,0].axis('off')
                ax[3,2].axis('off')
                #---------------------------------
                ax[3,1].cla()
                ax[3,1].nii_data(nii_data[:,:,9,i],cmap='gray', interpolation=None)
                ax[3,1].set_title("frame {}".format(i))
                ax[3,1].axis('off')
                #---------------------------------
                # Note that using time.sleep does *not* work here!
                #---------------------------------
                plt.pause(.05)
            plt.close('all')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it is not quite clear to me how your output should look like because the second column in the image has more entries than the others.
Please clarify this better in your questions as well as updating your code which is not working due to inconsistent variable names and messed up indenting.

In the meanwhile, I will try it with a first shot where your goal is to print all your slices on the x-axis whereas each frame is on the y-axis.
The code I adapted that it will print for the first three slices the first four frames.

```
#==================================
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#==================================
# load image (4D) [X,Y,Z_slice,time]
nii_img  = nib.load(path)
nii_data = nii_img.get_fdata()

#===================================================
number_of_slices = 3
number_of_frames = 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots(number_of_frames, number_of_slices,constrained_layout=True)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('4D Nifti Image')
fig.suptitle('4D_Nifti 10 slices 30 time Frames', fontsize=16)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()

for slice in range(number_of_slices):
    for frame in range(number_of_frames):
        ax[frame, slice].imshow(nii_data[:,:,slice,frame],cmap='gray', interpolation=None)
        ax[frame, slice].set_title("layer {} / frame {}".format(slice, frame))
        ax[frame, slice].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

The sample output for a black image looks like this:
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHqs8.png)

**Update - 05.04.2020** 
Given the information from the discussion in the comments here the updated version:

```
#==================================
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import ceil
#==================================
# Load image (4D) [X,Y,Z_slice,time]
nii_img = nib.load(path)
nii_data = nii_img.get_fdata()

#===================================================
number_of_slices = nii_data.shape[2]
number_of_frames = nii_data.shape[3]

# Define subplot layout 
aspect_ratio = 16./9
number_of_colums = int(number_of_slices / aspect_ratio)
if( number_of_slices % number_of_colums > 0):
    number_of_colums += 1
number_of_rows = ceil(number_of_slices / number_of_colums)

# Setup  figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(number_of_rows, number_of_colums,constrained_layout=True)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('4D Nifti Image')
fig.suptitle('4D_Nifti {} slices {} time Frames'.format(number_of_slices, number_of_frames), fontsize=16)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()

for frame in range(number_of_frames):
    for slice, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
        # For every slice print the image otherwise show empty space.
        if slice < number_of_slices:
            ax.imshow(nii_data[:,:,slice,frame],cmap='gray', interpolation=None)
            ax.set_title("layer {} / frame {}".format(slice, frame))
            ax.axis('off')
        else:
            ax.axis('off')

    plt.pause(0.05)

plt.close('all')
```

The output will look like: [second sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXL6Q.jpg)

Comment: the main issue here is that I have dataset, each image in the data set has different number of frames and slices, and I want to plot s much images inside the figure as slices number, and each image of slice should change frames, not just last image as you can see from last image here in my case.

Comment: here is a data sample of my data-set images: [sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BtuaZDJ4r5pLORcJmylgUCfmLFYrdAUO) The Figure should have **s** shapes and the shapes update the frame f each time interval (say 350 ms) so they will look like animations

Comment: I use **nibabel** library to read the image from Nifti format to numpy

Comment: To prevent that I misunderstood your question I start from scratch.
Is it correct that for **one** 4D Nifti image with the shape (X,Y,slices, frames) you want to create *only one* figure with subplots of different slice and frame configurations?

Comment: yes, I want to plot one figure with all slices inside, it should contain **S** subplot, each of them will show an animation(**f** frames) with time interval (let's say 350ms).

Comment: Does it mean for in the first animation step you would like to show all the slices of time frame t and in the next animation step you want to show the same slices at the time frame t+1? Something like this: (https://imgur.com/a/dRKMbC3)

Comment: Perfect. Do you have any restriction how the output should look like in terms of image layout such as fixed number of slices which are shown always or should the layout adapt to the number of slices? E.g. if you have 20 slices, you want 5 columns and 4 rows , if you have 30 slices, you want to have 6 columns and 5 rows and if you have 100 slices, you want something like 12 columns and 9 rows.

Comment: the layout should adapt to the number of slices.

Comment: Please check out the added code if this is what you needed. If yes please mark it as correct answer and I will clean up the answer as good as possible.